# If Statements in Python Class Methods

Tags: python, class, if-statement

I am new to python and practicing classes. I've created a simple class to create employee objects. I have yet to use conditional statements in a class method and am coming across the following error when running my code:

NameError: name 'Tax' is not defined

Under the TaxDed method, I have added if/elif/else statements based on the employee's salary. I then try to format/use it under the **str** constructor, which refers to the Tax variable as self.Tax.

I thought I had defined what Tax is, so am unsure why I have a name error

I apologize if this is an easy fix, I'm still getting my head around classes and the use of .self

My code is below:

```
    class Employee():
        
        Employment_Contract = "Amazon Employee"
        
        def __init__(self, FName, LName, JobTitle, GSalary):
            '''initalise first name, last name, job title and gross salary'''
            self.FName = FName
            self.LName = LName
            self.JobTitle = JobTitle
            self.GSalary = GSalary
        
        def PSalaryAmendment(self, PSalaryChange):
            '''performance related salary amendment'''
            self.GSalary += PSalaryChange

        def TaxDed(self):
            '''Tax calculation and net salary'''
            if self.GSalary > 150_000:
                Tax = ((self.GSalary - 150_000) * 0.45) + ((150_000 - 50271) * 0.4) + ((50270 - 12571) * 0.2)
                NetSalary = self.GSalary - Tax
            elif self.GSalary > 12571:
                Tax = (self.GSalary - 12571) * 0.2
                NetSalary = self.GSalary - Tax
            else:
                Tax = 0
                NetSalary = self.GSalary - Tax
        
        def __str__(self):
            '''When object called presents as string instead of memory location'''
            return '''\t Full Name: {FName} {LName} 
            \n \t Role: {JobTitle} 
            \n \t Employment Contract: {Employment_Contract} 
            \n \t Annual Gross GBP Salary: {GSalary} 
            \n \t Net of Tax {Tax} 
            \n \t Net Salary {NetSalary}'''.format(FName = self.FName, 
            LName = self.LName, 
            Employment_Contract = self.Employment_Contract, 
            JobTitle = self.JobTitle, 
            GSalary = self.GSalary,
            Tax = self.Tax, NetSalary = self.NetSalary)

    #Creating an instance object from my class
    Employee1 = Employee("Bob", "Builder", "Software Developer", 30_000)

    Employee1.PSalaryAmendment(-5000)

    print(Employee1)
```

Comment: Where do you ever assign `self.Tax` in this code? Point out the specific line, please.

Comment: (you have a _local variable_ `Tax` in some places, but I don't see a member variable Tax ever assigned; also, these aren't class methods, they're instance methods).

Comment: (`TaxDed` doesn't currently save any of the values it calculates, so they just get thrown away when it's done; also, you aren't actually calling it anywhere, so in practice it's never even getting a chance to calculate the values and then throw them away).

Comment: Assuming you wrote that line in answer to my question -- how does the line `def __str__(self):` assign `self.Tax`?

Comment: @AppleBS, If it's initialized to `0`, how can someone tell if it was set by `TaxDed` being called, or never set at all? Better to initialize to `None` so the invalid/unset state is clearly distinguishable, or to invoke `TaxDed` from the constructor (so it has always been given a correct value).

Answer (score 1):

`Tax` and `self.Tax` are two different variables. `Tax` is local to the method its used in. `self.Tax` belongs to the instance of an `Employee` object. If you want to use the variable `self.Tax` in a method, you need to assign a value to it first (usually in the `__init__` method).

In your case, I think you mean to assign to `self.Tax` in the if statement in your `TaxDed` method, then you can later read from it in your `__str__` method. Even then, you should still initialize it to some default value in `__init__` to guarantee that it is defined.

Comment: ...though the OP would need to additionally _call_ the `TaxDed` method, whether from `str()` or after each update to `self.GSalary`.